# Wordpress Contact form 7 error while mail recieving

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I am Developing a wordpress site and using a contact form 7 plugin  for contact us page.
When i enter all the datas into fields, the contact form showing **"Message sending Successfully,Thank You "** and i got mail.
I am Configured mail like below...

**Form :**

```
<div class="flexibleFormContainer">
<div class="flexFormInputBlock">
<label for="ff_Name1" class="flexFormBlockLabel">
    * Your Name:
</label>
<div class="flexFormFieldHTML">
    [text* Namex id:ff_Name1 class:flexInputSimple] </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div><div class="flexFormInputBlock">
<label for="ff_emailAddress1" class="flexFormBlockLabel">
    * Your Email Addres:
</label>
<div class="flexFormFieldHTML">
    [email* emailAddress id:ff_emailAddress1 class:flexInputSimple] </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div><div class="flexFormInputBlock">
<label for="ff_messageTopic1" class="flexFormBlockLabel">
Your Message:
</label>
<div class="flexFormFieldHTML">
    [textarea messageTopic id:ff_messageTopic1 class:flexInputTextarea]</div>
</div><div class="flexFormSubmitBlock">
        [submit id:ff_submitRequest1 class:submitRequest "Submit"]<input type="reset" class="submitRequest" value="Reset" />
</div>
</div>
```

**MessageBody**

```
 From : [emailAddress]

 Name :  [Namex]

 Message : [messageTopic].
```

**To** =
     ***my email id (in current format)***

**From**  =
     ***[Namex]<[emailAddress]>***

**Subject** = 
    ***Contact Us***

I am getting Email like below

```
Hi,

 You've had a form submission on my *wordpress website*  from *Johns**<johns@myhost.com>.*
```

What is this error. Anybody please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Looking at those special tags, it doesn't look like you're inside PHP.

Comment: is there any error in form ?

Comment: I couldn't be 100% certain. Have you read through the entire documentation? **https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/**

Comment: yes. am getting mail successfully in my previous sites and used many times this plugin. i dont getting what is going now...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, I think that you should to use an e-mail from your website domain. This code shows that you are trying to send to you an e-mail with mail that user inputed in your form. This way will not work, you need to send form with an e-mail from your domain email.

***To = my email id (in current format)***

***From = [Namex]<[emailAddress]>***
(here, you need to remove[Namex] and <[emailAdress]> and than put your domain e-mail, like wordpress@yourdomain.com).

***Subject = Contact Us***

Hope this helped you anyway